# VBScript Lauched via URL with arguments

Tags: variables, url, vbscript, arguments

I have a VBScript that is hosted in a network share. I have a link set up on a page to access that script via the web browser (i.e. \\server\script.vbs). Is it possible to pass in a variable/argument into that script via a hyperlink? I already tried \\server\script.vbs Argument and \\server\script.vbs%20Argument neither work. The script works fine with no argument. I scoured the web trying to find a way and fear that it is not possible so I thought I would ask here before I just make separate scripts with the arguments built in instead. The script sample is below:

`Dim Var1
If Wscript.Arguments.Count = 0 then
    WScript.Echo "Missing parameters"
Else
    Var1 = wscript.arguments(0)
    MsgBox "Passed in Variable: " + Var1
End If`

Comment: What do you mean via hyperlink?

Comment: @Barney I mean that I have a link on a webpage that points to \\server\script.vbs I was hoping for a way to pass a variable/argument into that VBS but just adding it to the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ASP, but you need to add the feature to the IIS role on the web server, configure the authentication (strongly recommend Windows authentication, NOT anonymous), and create an ASP page to capture the inline parameter (querystring) value and display it.  If the page is "test.asp", the sample below would be called at http://myserver/test.asp?arg1=123.  It would display "You entered: 123"

```
<%
x = Trim(Request.QueryString("arg1"))
Response.Write "You entered: " & x
%>
```

Comment: I would also suggest you look at using PowerShell Web Console.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am hosting the links on a Sharepoint page so I cant really setup an ASP page. I figured what I was looking for was not possible. Ill just make separate VBS files.

Comment: @mikefletcher85 if that is the case, why accept the answer?

Comment: I would be careful of allowing custom script code to execute on a SharePoint or other production server.  It could easily cause problems for the other services.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can, however you could link instead to an ASP page and have it run the VBS file - this code for that page should be close:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=vbscript>
   dim oWs
   Set oWs= CreateObject("WScript.shell")
   oWs.Run "\\yourserver\yourscript.vbs?ParameterNameHere=" & Request.QueryString("ParameterNameHere"), 1, True
   Set oWs = Nothing  
</SCRIPT>
```